# How to caution your opinion or judgement may sound biased in an idiomatic way?

Tags: phrase-choice, idiom-request

I was talking with my friend about my brother. My friend was a bit critical of my brother because of something he did. "My brother is one of the finest people", I told my friend. How can I introduce that sentence in an idiomatic way with another sentence suggesting my judgement or testimony my not be taken seriously and may sound biased because of the blood relationship with my brother?

Something along the lines of:

Look, my judgement may sound biased but he is one of the finest people.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you could say this, some that come to mind are:

> I know he’s my brother, but he really is one of the finest people.

> I’m not just saying this (because he’s my brother) - he really is one of the finest people.

You may even simply start with:

> I know this could sound biased, but honestly...